# Assembler. Изменение HEX по ходу программы

Tags: ассемблер

Есть программа (*PE*-файл) `1.exe`

Допустим в ячейке `000AF503` есть *HEX*-код:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Каким образом при помощи команд *Assembler*, которые будут внутри этого же `1.exe`, можно изменить код именно этой ячейки на другой?

например, на:

```
11 11 11 22 22 22 33 33 33 44 44 44 55 55 55 66
```

Comment: "Допустим в ячейке 000AF503 есть HEX-код" - ну вот не хранится в ячейках hex-код.

Answer (score 2):

Если эти данные находятся в области данных (то есть там, где есть доступ на запись), то все просто - обычная команда [mov](http://www.programmersclub.ru/assembler3/). и аккуратно, ячейка за ячейкой переписываем. Вам скорее всего придется побайтно.

Если же данные находятся в области кода (которая по умолчанию доступна только на чтение), то тут придется снять защиту и только потом писать.

Comment: Сразу 3 вопроса появились: 1) как командой mov править ячейку? 2) как можно править сразу в HEX? 3) как снять защиту на запись? Извиняюсь за обилие вопросов - просто материалов по асму в сети ну оочень мало.

Comment: 1) через регистр процессора. Вначале в него записываете, потом в ячейку памяти.
2) любым редактором, который это позволяет. К примеру http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/
3) соотвествующим вызовом апи - VirtualProtect

Comment: rep movsb если нужно сразу несколько байт скопировать, IMHO и короче, и проще.

Comment: @СемёнСавенко  материалов по ассемблеру полно, только это не сборники решений каких-то задач.

Comment: да, только нужно подготовить адреса источника и приемника, а также где то в памяти хранить нужные данные.

Comment: Это называется "самомодифицирующийся код".